# Mobile Application UI development and integration process

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I'm looking forward to implement a process to develop and integrate user interfaces for mobile developments in for a mobile development team. Currently we are facing problems such as communicating user interface requirements such as screen sizes, etc... by the developers to the UI designers and when developers receive the designs from the UI designers there are alignments issues, low image qualities, font sizes are different and so on. How do the designers test whether their designs are appropriate for the respective screen sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would strongly recommend reading [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) documentation carefully as it describes very important aspects when designing your app for multiple screens

Second, Android Development Tools recently added very useful feature to *preview* your app on multiple screens at the same time. See the attached image, where I am highlighting the button where you can select `Preview All Screens`

[image: Preview the app on multiple screens]